# Redis cluster error "ClusterDown Hash slot not served"

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

After running windows redis 3.2 for over 4 years without issue I am now getting the intermittent error "ClusterDown Hash slot not served" when connecting from my client application. The error occurs on roughly 50% of the calls to redis.

The client uses stackexchange redis with coding in C#.

We have 2 redis servers set up as master ports (7000, 7001, 7002) and secondary on ports (7003, 7004, 7005)

Using Redis Insight to view the redis server we see the error below, but only sometimes.
"The seed nodes have different cluster configuration. This means that your application may be reading from two different clusters."

We have inspected the all configurations and tried failovers with no success fixing the issue.

Any idea on what to look at would be very appreciated.